# Mirror Image and output as webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to make a simple program in Python which uses pyvirtualcam and the OBS Virtual Cam with it, which simply takes an image from a webcam and outputs it mirrored to the OBS Virtual cam. Sadly, I don't know how I can convert the image from cv2 to an RGBA NP Array. This is my Code:

```
import cv2
import pyvirtualcam
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('frame', 800,800)

with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=30) as cam:
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        print(frame.shape)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ditin2/Desktop/test_cam.py", line 33, in <module>
    cam.send(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Ditin2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualcam\camera.py", line 94, in send
    _native_windows.send(frame)
RuntimeError: frame must have 4 channels (rgba)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `frame` is in RGB format you can convert to RGBA with:

```
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
```

One note, in case `frame` is in BGR, which I suspect it is (I'm pretty sure cap.read() returns image in BGR), you will need to use:

```
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
```